# Unknown integer conversion for string length >10 in cocos2d/Xcode applications(iOS 7.0)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios7, integer

I am working with `cocos2d 2.0` and iOS7.0. And while trying to get the integer value or float value of a string with larger length(usually > 10), I'm always getting some unknown outputs as below:

when string length <= 10:

```
    NSString *amount = @"1234567890";
    NSLog(@"AmountStr=|%@|",amount);
    NSLog(@"Amount   =|%d|",[amount integerValue]);
```

Output(getting correct integer value):

```
  AmountStr=|1234567890|
  Amount   =|1234567890| --
```

---

But, when string length >10, that is :

```
    NSString *amount = @"12345678901"; -- added a '1' after the string, so length = 11
    NSLog(@"AmountStr=|%@|",amount);
    NSLog(@"Amount   =|%d|",[amount integerValue]);
```

then I am getting the output as :

```
    AmountStr=|12345678901|  -- This is correct
    Amount   =|2147483647|   -- But what about this..!!! :O
```

I have tried `integerValue`, `intValue`, and `floatValue`. Every time, same error occurs. So how do I findout the int value of a string with length greater than 10. Please help me.

Comment: The problem is called integer overflow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"Amount =|%lli|",[amount longLongValue]);
```

You're trying to print a number as an integer which is larger than the largest number an integer can hold.  It's not even about number of digits.  Trying to do this with `3000000000` would replicate the "error".

There's also `doubleValue` method for `NSString`, which will give you more significant digits than `floatValue`.

Moreover, I'm a little surprised that using `%d` with the call to `integerValue` even works.  `intValue` returns an `int`.  But `integerValue` returns an `NSInteger`.  Normally, when using format specifiers with `NSInteger`, you need to use `%ld` and cast the `NSInteger` to a `long`...

And for up to 38-digits, you can always use `NSDecimalNumber`.

```
NSDecimalNumber *myNum = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:amount];
NSLog(@"%@", [myNum descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]]);
```